# Python List Trouble... 2 Lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to learn python and been playing around with code. It's getting pretty confusing though.

```
def Music():
  myList1 = ["bob","coldplay"]
  myList2 = ["dylan"]
  if len(myList1)>len(myList2):#if 2 > 1
      a = len(myList1) # a = 2
      abc = len(myList1) - len(myList2) #abc = 2 - 1 = 1
      print(abc)# print 1
      for i in range(a): # for i in range 2
            print(myList1[i]) # print [0] and [1]
            if (i-abc >=0):
                print(myList2[i-abc])
                abc-=1
   else:
       a = len(myList2)
       abc = len(myList1) - len(myList2)
       print(abc)        
       for i in range(a):
            print(myList2[i])
```

The output of this code is

```
1
bob
coldplay
dylan
```

I want it to output

```
1
bob
dylan
coldplay
```

Comment: can you please update your post with correct indentation? I can guess what your code actually is, but it is best if you correct the indentation yourself.

Comment: this is for sure not a valid python code since the indentation is messed up and I can't tell the where the else statement belong to

Comment: Also would be nice if you say what is the purpose of the code.

Comment: Your data structure seems very odd. What if you add another artist, would you get `["Bob", "Coldplay", "Jimi"]` and `["Dylan", "Hendrix"]`? How would you match the second list back to the first?

Comment: Sorry everyone fixed it.

Comment: And @jonrsharpe yeah I never actually thought about that. What would I have to do?

Comment: @user3394808 why have two lists? Why not have a single list: `["Bob Dylan", "Coldplay"]`. Or, if you want to keep first and last name separate, a list of tuples: `[("Bob", "Dylan"), ("Coldplay",)]`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the reason for 2 lists is because of I'm trying to separate the 2 from each other by a "-". So x is "bob" and y is "dylan" and I'm concatenating them together in a string. A web url creator.

Comment: @user3394808 then use the tuples, and `"-".join(artist)`. Otherwise you will have to pad the second list with e.g. `None`.

Comment: @user3394808, As others have noted, the data structure is a bit screwy. In general, if you are able to make a more sensical structure, do so, or if you're truly stuck with it, explain why you're stuck with it in SO posts. It may very well be worth cleaning the data first.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList1 = ["bob","coldplay"]
myList2 = ["dylan"]

for i in range(max(len(myList1), len(myList2))):
    if i < len(myList1):
        print myList1[i]
    if i < len(myList2):
        print myList2[i]
```

It's not a very pythonic way of doing things though.  Consider having one list of music objects and overload the `__str__()` method on it.  Then the program becomes:

```
class Music:

    def __init__(self, first_name, second_name = None):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.second_name = second_name
        return

    def __str__(self):
        if self.second_name is None:
            return self.first_name
        else:            
            return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.second_name)


music_list = [Music("bob", "dylan"), Music("coldplay"), ]
for music in music_list:
    print music
```

That's not quite what you asked for.  You can always move the `__str__` functionality into the for loop and customize it as you wish (to get the newline between first_name and second_name).  This second way is a bit more complicated for very small programs but makes writing larger programs easier.

A middle ground approach is to use lists of tuples or lists of lists..

```
music_list = [("bob", "dylan"), ("coldplay,) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line `if (i-abc >=0)`. `abc` is the length difference between `myList1` and `myList2`. If `myList1` is really big, `i` will be smaller than `abc` for a very long time, and myList2 won't be printed for that time:

```
 for i in range(a): # for i in range 2
        print(myList1[i]) # print [0] and [1]
        if (i-abc >=0) # bug is here 
            print(myList2[i-abc]) # and here. should just be print myList2[i]
            abc-=1
```

Instead you want to print it as long as it's not out of range:

```
if i < len(myList2):
     print myList2[i]
```